# Reopen vote audit failed for Chrome Bug

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits

I failed an audit in the Reopen queue for https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/16064794.

The question is specifically expressing that there is a bug in Chrome.  There is no code associated with the question and the updates to the question do NOT provide any additional context, since they are merely status updates on the state of the bug:

> UPDATE Apr 25 2017 : After a Chrome update (58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)) the
>   bug is still there. This bug is not present on Chromium (59.0.3070.0)
>   for those who still want to work with Chrome(ish) solutions.
>
> UPDATE May 5 2017 : Chrome update (58.0.3029.96 (64-bit)) : Bug still
>   there

I don't understand how

1) The question is appropriate for Stack Overflow since it feels more appropriate to Super User

2) The audit failed at all since it seems perfectly reasonable to leave the question closed since the updates add zero additional context.

Comment: Well, I have voted to close it as off topic for super users.  It has also been down voted by someone so it should no longer be used as an audit.  It was a bad audit but it should be gone now.

Comment: Also don't feel too bad.  Someone else also failed this as an audit.

Comment: @NathanOliver I appreciate the information and the feedback :)